# Display all the data in a checkbox that are coming from the api in vuejs

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am facing an issue where i want to display the data of an array from api in checkbox. I have list of checkbox calling from another api and i want to show the selected values with checked in that list of checkbox but i cannot

Here is the sample of code:

```
             <ul class="checkboxes">
                <li v-for="(role, i) in roles" :key="i">
                    <input
                      :id="'checkbox' + i"
                      type="checkbox"
                      v-model="selected"
                      :value="role"
                    />
                    {{ role.name }}
                </li>
              </ul>
```

All though all the checkbox are displaying but it is not displaying the ones with checked that are coming from backend.

For example: i have 10 values inside `roles`. but not showing checked in the page.
Roles looks like this:
`roles:['x:list', 'y:list']`
please help

Comment: Can you show us what `roles` looks like?

Comment: @maxshuty i have edited the code, of what roles look like

Answer (score 1):

I built a sample component showing how to bind an array of roles to checkboxes:

```
<template>
  <div class="bind-multiple-checkboxes">
    <h3>Select Roles</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-check" v-for="(role, index) in roles" :key="index">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" :id="'checkbox' + index" v-model="role.selected">
          <label class="form-check-label" :for="'checkbox' + index">
            {{ role.name }}
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        roles: [
          {
            name: 'role1',
            selected: true
          },
          {
            name: 'role2',
            selected: false
          },
          {
            name: 'role3',
            selected: false
          },
          {
            name: 'role4',
            selected: true
          },
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is important that you have an empty array to bind the selected values in two ways. note that `role.name` does not exist, since role is a string in your array:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    roles: ['x:list', 'y:list', 'z:list'],
    selected: ['z:list'] // fill if you want a checkbox prefilled
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <ul class="checkboxes">
    <li v-for="role in roles" :key="role.id">
    <label>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      :value="role"
      v-model="selected"
     />
     {{ role }}</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>{{ selected }}</p>
</div>
```

you can read more about [input bindings here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox)